# UILabel update the text, but the old content is still on the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uilabel

There are 2 view controllers: A and B. A UILabel in AViewController which should be changed by the value from that of BViewController. I used the delegate to transfer the value.

In BViewController.h:

```
@protocol BViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void)finishWithText:(NSString *)text;

@end


@interface BViewController : UIViewController<CustomizeTextViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *textLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<BViewControllerDelegate> textDelegate;

@end
```

---

In BViewController.m:

```
_textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(180, 120, 120, 30)];
_textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
_textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
_textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
_textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
_textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
_textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
_textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
_textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[self.view addSubview:_textField];

-(void)didTapFinish {
    if ([_textDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(finishWithText:)]) {
        [_textDelegate finishWithText:_textField.text];
    }

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

---

In A ViewController, there is a UIImageView (imageView) and a UILabel on the view. imageView and lable are properties.
    -(void)viewDidLoad{
    ....
    _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,100,100)];
    _label.text = @"old text";
    [_imageView addSubview:_label];
    ....
    }

When tap the label, B ViewController will be created as below:

```
BViewController *bVC = [[BViewContorller alloc] init];
bVC.textDelegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bVC animated:YES];

#pragma mark --BViewContorllerDelegate

- (void)finishWithText:(NSString *)text{
    _label.text = text;
}
```

---

But the result is when back from BViewController, the new text you typed in BViewController is on the label of AViewController, but the old one "old text" is still on the screen.

And I made the UILabel movable, when I pan the label with the new text,the label was moved to other position, but the "old text" is still on the screen which is not subview and can not be selected. And I also print out the all the subviews, there is only one imageVIew and one UILabelView.

What is the matter?

Comment: Your code is not working like this - in controller A the label is only a local variable? Then you can't access it in the finishWithText function. It somehow sounds like you are creating the label in controller A again when you return from controller B - hence two fields, one with the new text and one with the old (that's the newly created one i suppose).

Comment: I omitted some code here try to simplify the question. The label should be a property, or claimed as global variable. Sorry for the confusion. And I also tried the 3rd method:  get all the subviews and find the UILabel to change the text as below:    NSArray *subviews = [self.view subviews];     for (UIView *view in subviews){if([view isKindofClass:[UILabel class]){((UILabel *)view).text = text;}}      And it's also the same result.

Comment: it's quite simple - if you see the new text AND the old text in controller a's view, there have to be two labels on it, so apparently two label's are created - set a breakpoint on the code where you create the label and see if and why it happens

Comment: I tried to get all the subviews of the imageView but there is no more UILable, only one lable with new text. But the old text is still on the screen.

Comment: as i said, that can't be. print all views of your current window with po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription] in debugging mode, and you'll find the two labels

Comment: I tried po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription] in debugging mode, there is only one label with new text. But "old text" is still on screen.

Comment: It's my fault. I made a screen copy in viewWillDisappear, and update the imageView in viewWillAppear. Thank you for all the helps. Sorry for the convenience.

Answer (score 3):

Where are you calling the following code?

```
UILable *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,100,100)];
label.text = @"old text";
[imageView addSubview:label];
```

Based on the behavior you described, you are probably calling it twice. At some point it's adding a second UILabel. Make sure to put it in a function that's only called once, like `viewDidLoad`

Comment: it is called in viewDidLoad and label is the property which only created once.   I updated the code in my question.   -(void)viewDidLoad{ .... _label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,100,100)]; _label.text = @"old text"; [_imageView addSubview:_label]; .... }

Comment: how is A view controller initialized? is through a storyboard?